# Getting "FileNotFoundError" when opening files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I've written a script to open, read, and then close a text file, but I keep getting an error message saying it can't find the file I specify.

I've massively reduced the code but I still get the same error message.

## The code:

```
txt = open("textf.txt", "r")
print(txt.read())
txt.close()
```

## The error message from running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\openfiles.py", line 1, in <module>
    txt = open("textf.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'textf.txt'
```

Comment: Try putting in the full path to your file. It's probably not in the directory the script is looking in.

Comment: Are your python script and this text file in the same directory? With this code they have to be.

Comment: @Anger What does the PATH have to do with this?

Comment: @wjandrea Yep, I was confused. Not running an executable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you run your code from.

You can use an absolute path (like c:/path/to/file/textf.txt)

Or you can use

```
import os
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(this_dir)
```

to check where your code is running, then move your file there.

Or you could add the path where the file is located to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I don't think altering the PATH environment variable would solve the problem. PATH is where the shell will look for executable files.